# Send email through azure web app through sendgrid

Tags: php, azure, post, sendgrid, forms, http-post

I have a website running on azure and I am able to receive emails.
I have Sendgrid account installed in my azure.
But I have subscriber form, I need to send thank you email to subscribers. I am not able to figure out how to get form data into my php sendgrid file.
Please help me out in getting form data into php.

```
My action_page.php file
    <?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'pwd'; 

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => 'subscriber email',
    'subject'   => 'testing from curl',
    'html'      => 'testing body',
    'text'      => 'testing body',
    'from'      => 'company email',
  );


$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// print everything out
print_r($response);

?>
```

HTML file

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="POST" >

  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">

  <br>

  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">

  <br>

  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">

  <br>

  <label>

  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" value="Yes" style="margin-bottom:15px">

  <span style="color:#f08615"> Sign up for latest news</span>

    </label>

    <br>



<input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe">

</form>
```

Comment: Check [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) about dealing with forms. There are also thousands of tutorials out there about using forms with PHP, if you just do a simple Google search.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you sendgrid api-key is `pwd`

Comment: Hi Magnus,  I already have a code which is working for php to get the content. My concern is about SendGrid API which is used for azure hosted websites. So the normal php coding is not working on azure to send email and get contents entered in form.